# In Eclipse, how can I exclude some files (maybe based on the .svn extension or filename) from being copied to the output folder?

Tags: java, eclipse, svn, build-process

I'm developing a Java application using Eclipse. My project has two source directories that are both built and then some files are copied into the output folder. From the output directory I then run my application and all works well.

However, I keep having these warnings:

[Snapshot from Problems tab in Eclipse http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/128c1af93f.png](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/128c1af93f.png)

Anyone know how to get rid of these warnings? Maybe by excluding some files, maybe based on the .svn extension or filename, from the build process? If so, how would I go about excluding those?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Have you tried to add

`**/.svn/`

to the *Exclusion patterns* at the *Source* preferences of the project's build path settings?

Answer (score 9):

You could also try installing the Subversion plugin ([Subclipse](http://subclipse.tigris.org/)) for Eclipse.

Comment: Subclipse manages these components for you in eclipse so they don't interfere with your build process.

Comment: I use Subversive, and generally this works too. Once I had this problems still and had to kill off my classes folder, disconnect the project from SVN, rebuild the project and then reconnect it to SVN. This flushed whatever caused the problem in this instance.

Answer (score 2):

Sure, that easy:
at Project Properties -- Java Build Path you can add exclusion filters on every source folder.
There, you can add an exclusion pattern as *.svn

Answer (score 1):

That sounds like your building process is using versionned directory within your subversion workspace.

Should you not have your 'output' folder and/or your 'tst' folder be made 'private' ? (that is without any .svn, and ignored by subversion)

Answer (score 0):

Right click on the source file > Build Path > Exclude.