# Tortoise SVN: deleted folders reappear after being removed with the Repo Browser

Tags: tortoisesvn

Windows XP SP3; TortoiseSVN 1.6.16, Build 21511 - 32 Bit, which is the current version at the moment.

We're using Eclipse Helios for some Android development.  When one of the projects was first checked in using TortoiseSVN, the bin and gen folders were included.  I'm trying to delete them from SVN.

I went to the Repo Browser and deleted the bin and gen folders from the project.  The Repo Browser log shows two "Deleted" entries for revision 40583.  I then went to my working copy and did an SVN Update.  It deleted the folders, as expected.  The File Explorer shows a green icon for the project.

Next, I ran Eclipse and did Project/Clean.  The bin and gen folders were created.  The gen folder shows the purple question mark icon as an unversioned folder, as expected.  The bin folder, however shows a red exclamation point icon, and it and all of its child folders all contain a .svn version control subfolder.  If I exit Eclipse and do a TortoiseSVN Cleanup, the bin folder temporarily shows a green icon and then immediately switches back to the red exclamation point icon.

What's going on?

Comment: Did you "refreshed" (F5) your project in Eclipse before you did a "Project/Clean"?

Comment: @splash: I've tried with and without refreshing (F5) before Project/Clean, and get the same results, the bin folder comes back with the .svn subfolders.

Comment: Additionally, if I try TortoiseSVN's extended menu item "Delete (keep local)" on the bin folder, I get the error: "'bin' is not under version control" which is expected, and makes me think Eclipse is possibly restoring it from a cache?  I've just recently started Android development and am new to Eclipse, so there may be an IDE configuration that's involved somehow.

Comment: I think I found the cause of the problem.  Eclipse is copying the .svn folders from the src tree to bin.  I'm tweaking the project's Java Build Path settings to see if I can get it to ignore the .svn folders.

Comment: Found how to correctly set the Java Build Path exclusion list with `**/.svn/*` here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1709810/why-is-eclipse-trying-to-copy-my-svn-folders-from-src-to-bin-and-how-can-i-make/1710919#1710919

Answer (score 1):

You should install a SVN client in eclipse, and don't use TortoiseSVN altogether on the same directory as eclipse is working on. This is the root cause of your problem, and it will come again and again.

So the proper use is:

1. Install a SVN client like subversive or subclipse inside eclipse.
2. Depending on the client you choose, checkout the project from your subversion repository using the menu entries of the client you have installed.
3. After having checked-out the project, check the properties of the root folder of the project. They should define that the `bin` folder (or `target` if you are using Maven) should be ignored.
4. If you have to add that property, ensure to commit it, so others will not have the same problem.