# could not find monkey.apk in eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, apk

Hi I am building a new project but seems facing a big problem when I try to run the problem.
I have tried to clean and rebuild but it does not work.

I hope someone can help me. Thanks.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.monkey"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission           android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x20000" android:required="true" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >


    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"    android:value="AIzaSyCi43x8rh1xwonf15SQ2faHLPKCJUkzAn8" />
    <activity android:theme="@*android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="com.example.monkey.Home" android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <activity android:name="com.example.monkey.SettingPreferences" android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity android:name="com.example.monkey.CategoryList" android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity android:name="com.example.monkey.MenuList" android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity android:name="com.example.monkey.MenuDetail" android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity android:name="com.example.monkey.ShareMenu" android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity android:name="com.example.monkey.Contact" android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity android:name="com.example.monkey.News" android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity android:name="com.example.monkey.NewsDetail" android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity android:name="com.example.monkey.YourOrder" android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
    <activity android:name="com.example.monkey.Reservation" android:screenOrientation="portrait" />
</application>
```

**Logcat**

```
[2014-03-16 22:24:11 - monkey] ------------------------------ 
[2014-03-16 22:24:11 - monkey] Android Launch! 
[2014-03-16 22:24:11 - monkey] adb is running normally. 
[2014-03-16 22:24:11 - monkey] Could not find monkey.apk!
```

Comment: Here is the error come out.
Android Launch!
adb is running normally.
Could not find monkey.apk!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has happened to me before. I solved it by doing the following:

1. Right click your project and click "Properties".
2. Select Android from the list on the left.
3. Uncheck the "Is Library" checkbox.

Alternatively, you could try the following:

1. Right click your project.
2. Click Android Tools -> Fix Project Properties.
3. Clean your project (Project -> Clean...).
4. Try to run the project again.

Also, make sure your Android SDK Build-tools are installed. You can check this and install them by going to Window -> Android SDK Manager.

Alternative solutions could be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8038971/why-is-my-updated-eclipse-android-setup-not-building-my-apk-anymore) if you are missing the `bin` directory.

Comment: It is unchecked as default so it does not work for me. Thank you anyway

Comment: Then try to right click your project -> Android Tools -> Fix properties. Then do a Clean and try again.

Comment: I have tried a min before but still does not work :(

Comment: I discover that I dont get a bin folder in the left hand side. Is it a problem?

Comment: See if this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8038971/why-is-my-updated-eclipse-android-setup-not-building-my-apk-anymore

Comment: What was the problem?

Comment: I have no idea but i have tried the link where you provided and restart the eclipse. Finally everything is fine. Thanks bro