# How do I get Eclipse CDT to ignore files

Tags: c++, git, perforce, eclipse-cdt

I have a C++ project in Eclipse.  The project uses Perforce and Eclipse has the Perforce plugin installed.  Everything was fine, until I decided to create a **git** repo in my project.  I created the git repo to snapshot some changes which I wasn't ready to commit.  Everything was fine until I refreshed my files in Eclipse.  Two problems have occurred:

1. Eclipse found my .git folder, and indexed all of the files inside of it.
2. Eclipse also decided to add all the git file to my pending change list.

If I create a new file within Eclipse, I'd like it to add it to Perforce, but if it happens to find a file, I don't want it to do anything with it.  I'd also like to give Eclipse a list of file types to always ignore, just like I do with my .gitignore file.

I'm using the P4WSAD plugin, but I'm pretty sure the problem can occur anytime you have files you want Eclipse to not see.

Comment: I hope you mean gitignore, not hgignore - surely with git and perforce already in the mix you've got enough version control!

Comment: Is that the P4WSAD Eclipse plugin you are talking about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add a file `.p4ignore` in your project root and add everything you want **P4WSAD** to ignore, such as

```
.git
```

See [the docu on P4WSAD](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/doc.092/manuals/p4wsad/topics/adding.html) for more info.

That should take care of the `Perforce` part of your question. For the `Eclipse` part, please see this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/225375/).

Comment: The linked question works for java projects in Eclispe, but the option doesn't seem to be there for CDT projects.